# редирект 301 в htaccess без слэша в конце

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Добрый день!Нужно настроить редирект со страницы товаров со слэшем, на стр. товаров без слэша
Например при нажатии на:

```
http://semena-samara.ru/catalog/grunt/torf_fasko_9_0l_ogorodnik_verkhovoy.htm/
```

Должно переходить на:

```
http://semena-samara.ru/catalog/grunt/torf_fasko_9_0l_ogorodnik_verkhovoy.htm
```

Пробовал добавить в htacess следующие строки - ничего не выходит

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\/]$
RewriteRule ^/categories/(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избавился от "/" следующим образом:

```
#Condition for pages w/o "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/(.*)/(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```